# What's the difference between 'access' and 'modified' times in Windows folder structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

When I access the folder using `os.path.getmtime(folder_path)`, it does not return the modified time of a file. `os.path.getatime(folder_path)` returns the correct last modified time instead.

Comment: I just tested it in Windows 10 with Python 3.9.4 and got both correct modified time and access time of a file using `getmtime` and `getatime`, respectively. Please be more specific about your Windows and Python versions.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, a folder's modified time is the time when the **folder** was last updated, not when a file in the folder was last updated.

When you **create** a file in a folder, `getmtime(folder)` and `getatime(folder)` are both updated.

When you **edit** an existing file in a folder, only `getatime(folder)` is updated, not `getmtime(folder)`.

When you **read** an existing file in a folder, only `getatime(folder)` is updated, not `getmtime(folder)`.

To find when the latest file was updated in a folder, neither `getatime(folder)` nor `getmtime(folder)` will help. You need to loop through the files under the folder and use `getmtime(each_file_in_folder)`.